# Plugin with id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.GradleProjectPlugin' not found

Tags: android, onesignal

I'm trying to run my code in android studio

this is my error

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with
> id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.GradleProjectPlugin' not found.

This is my module code :

> apply plugin: "com.android.application" apply from: "../utils.gradle"
> apply plugin: "com.onesignal.androidsdk.GradleProjectPlugin"
>
> android {     compileSdkVersion 32    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
>
> defaultConfig {         applicationId "com.zakat"       minSdkVersion 19
> targetSdkVersion 32         versionCode getVersionCode(VERSION_MAJOR,
> VERSION_MINOR, VERSION_PATCH, VERSION_BUILD)      versionName
> getVersionName(VERSION_MAJOR, VERSION_MINOR, VERSION_PATCH)
> multiDexEnabled true        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true    }
>
> signingConfigs {        release {           def keystoreProperties =
> getKeystoreProperties
> file("../${project.property('keystore.properties')}")             storeFile
> file("../${project.property('keystore.file')}")           storePassword
> keystoreProperties["keystore.store.password"]             keyAlias
> keystoreProperties["keystore.key.alias"]          keyPassword
> keystoreProperties["keystore.key.password"]       }   }
>
> buildTypes {        debug {             buildConfigField "boolean", "LOGS", "true"
> buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV_ENVIRONMENT", "true"
> buildConfigField "boolean", "TEST_ADS", "false"
>
> ```
>       versionNameSuffix "-debug"      }
>
>   release {           buildConfigField "boolean", "LOGS", "false"
>       buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV_ENVIRONMENT", "false"
>       buildConfigField "boolean", "TEST_ADS", "false"
>
>       signingConfig signingConfigs.release            zipAlignEnabled true
>       minifyEnabled false             shrinkResources false           proguardFiles
> ```
>
> getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
> }   }
>
> compileOptions {        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
> targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8     }
>
> setProperty("archivesBaseName", getArtifactName(defaultConfig))
>
> // workaround for https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141132133
> configurations.all {        resolutionStrategy {            force
> "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-rc02"         }   } }
>
> dependencies {    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include:
> ["*.jar"])    implementation(name: "config", ext: "aar")  implementation
> "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-rc02" // workaround for
> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141132133  implementation
> "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5"    implementation
> "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"    implementation
> "com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8"    implementation
> "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"  implementation
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.3.0"     implementation
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4"   implementation
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4"   implementation
> "com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.1"  implementation
> "org.alfonz:alfonz-utility:0.9.2"     implementation
> "org.alfonz:alfonz-view:0.9.2"    classpath
> "gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.11.0"
> //classpath
> "gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1,
> 0.99.99]"     classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0" }
>
> apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

Can anyone help me? Thank you